# path of suporting files in OS X program?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I need some help for my OS X program.

I need the URL of a file inside the supporting files.

I have an array in which I save URLs from images and add them to a table view and if no images are chosen I want to add a question mark image (it is called "bild.jpg")

This bild.jpg is inside the supporting files but for later use I can't just save the name of the image because the array stores also URLs.

I need to have the URL of that image in the supporting file because it's easier to use the array for image initialization.

Is there a function to get the path or is there a standard path to the supporting files? I already search on the net but couldn't find anything that could help.

Comment: Your second paragraph is all one single sentence, and I can't really decypher what you have and what your problem is from it. What are "the supporting files of OS X"? Are the details of what you do with the URLs relevant?

Comment: it is a folder xcode atomaticaly creates wehn creating a project and you put in this folder files wich are inside your programm. thes files can be for example a picture of somthing wich others dosnt have on their system and if the program is on an other system it can still acess those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be talking about the application bundle and its resources directory rather than, say, a subdirectory in `~/Library/Application Support/...`, in which case you probably want something like:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"bild" withExtension:@"jpg"]
```

(See [the documentation for `NSBundle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html).)